# Single-pole switch with 3 hot wires (only 1 load and 1 switch)?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

The switch in the picture below (the circuit is closed) seems to only control a single load (a ceiling light fixture) and also seems to be the only switch controlling that fixture.  Why are there 3 hot wires?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two hot wires and one switch hot to the light.

The second hot wire is carrying power to another device(outlet) and is using the switch as a junction box.

If it is two wires instead of one wire with some insulation removed to go around the switch screw, then they should be connected to a wire nut and a short wire to the screw.

Comment: So this single-pole switch has a pair of holes in the back AND a pair of screws on one side.  Are they still violating code if they used BOTH the bottom screw AND the bottom hole to form the junction?

Comment: @mkk  No the holes in the back are in code, but not everybody likes them since they tend to be a source of problems more than the screws.  If possible it is recommended to use the screws, but most screws are one wire only.  Pigtails where you connect more than one wire together and then connect one wire to the screw are the preferred way of doing it.  The back stabs(holes) should only be used once, no removing and using a second time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Always-hot Power in
2. Always-hot Power onward to somewhere else
3. Switched power to the light

Presumably item 2 is what you're not thinking of. Unless this switch is the last thing on the circuit (evidently not) a cable goes onwards to power the next thing on the circuit.

Comment: Yeah that was one suggestion I checked out, but I have scoured this place for (2) and can't find a single other item except for the aforementioned fixture that is controlled by this switch

Comment: @mkk   It will not be controlled by the switch, but by the breaker in the panel.  They just used the switch as a means to carry power to another device(outlet, another switch).

Comment: Ahhh got it thanks!